# How do I turn off/hide landmarks on googlemaps

Tags: google-maps

I am using the google maps api v2 to build attraction guide mashup. Currently it shows some landmarks on the tiles it returns. I notice some of the geocoding of certain attractions is off.

Is there a way I can tell google to send back map tiles with no land marks? I cant seem to find any info on the api docs about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to request custom tiles from Google.  Your only option is to choose from the [available map types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMapType.G_NORMAL_MAP), or to generate your own tiles.

The Terrain map (`G_PHYSICAL_MAP`) might be more acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1):

As of Google Maps API v3, you can use the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to do exactly this.