# Is it possible to remove landmarks from google map with JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question, is it possible to remove all landmarks from the google map, so I could change the scale of the map without landmarks shown?

Comment: Do you want to remove markers or landmarks? What kind of landmark kindly elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for the response! If it's possible I'd like to remove all names from the map, to make it plain, without anything written on it.

Comment: See second answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1305397/87015

Comment: Yes, I read it, but it's not the exact thing I tried to make, anyway, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feed below styles into your map - `styles: [{"stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#fee379"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#fee379"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#f3f4f4"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#7fc8ed"}]},{},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#83cead"}]},{"elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"weight":0.9},{"visibility":"off"}]}]` inside mapOptions array. When you provide this mapoption to your google map, there will be no markers.

Answer (score 2):

> Google has provided a UI to generate the custom styles. Refer this
>   [link](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

[image]

For `react-google-maps` module

```
<GoogleMap options={{styles: mapStyles}}>
```

`mapStyles` is the custom style to be applied to the map.

Comment: Using the provided link works great. to initialize it with JS set the map options like this:
const mapOptions = { /* other options */, styles: GOOGLE_MAP_STYLES};
Replace GOOGLE_MAP_STYLES with the object generated from the afore-mentioned link.

Answer (score 2):

To hide poi labels, the code below is enough:

```
options: {
    styles: [
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
```